# How to remove a rule based promotion from a cart?

Tags: sap-commerce-cloud

I have a rule based promotion applied on my cart.

On the basis of an order entry containing a specific product I want to remove the promotion from the cart.

I tried the method in CartController but it didn't work with the rule based promotion.

How do I go ahead with this?

Answer (score 0):

This is not something that can/should be solved in the CartController. Even if you remove the promotion there, once a recalculation triggers, the promotion will be there again.

You should solve this in the conditions of your promotion. However, out of the box it's not possible to combine include and exclude conditions on qualifying products/categories.

You could look into [creating a custom condition](https://help.sap.com/viewer/e1391e5265574bfbb56ca4c0573ba1dc/v2005/en-US/98bd2273bde6468aad2c59340b141be1.html), depending on your requirements

Comment: I agree that if a single product or category can be used for promotion exclusion then this is just a config in the promotion itself. If something more customized is needed then here is the link to follow (the one in the above answer is broken).
https://help.sap.com/viewer/e1391e5265574bfbb56ca4c0573ba1dc/v2005/en-US/58de985a42c749b49818a624dea8e35e.html

Comment: I've updated the link in the answer, seems like something went wrong during saving